# Why is splice method removing only first array index in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, splice

I'm making a small application in React with the PokeAPI and am having issues with using the splice() method to remove an element (pokemon) from the array (team). No matter which element I pick to remove it only removes the first element in the array.

This is the function -- which is being passed down through props -- I'm using in order to delete the item.

```
removePokemon = (index) => {
  const team = [...this.state.team]
   team.splice(index, 1)
   this.setState({team})
  }
```

And here is the Team component where it's actually being used.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'


class Team extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.props.trainer && <p>{this.props.trainer}'s Team</p>}</h2>
                {this.props.team &&
                <div>
                    {this.props.team.map((pokemon, i) => (
                        <div key={pokemon.id}>
                            <span className='cardHeader'>#{pokemon.id} - {pokemon.name}</span>
                            <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemon.name}/>
                            <Button onClick={this.props.removePokemon}>Remove from team</Button>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                }

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Team;
```

Comment: `onClick={this.props.removePokemon}` vs `function removePokemon (index) { ... }` - What's missing on the left side?

Comment: Try adding some logging to your function - i.e. console.log to check what value index is, I believe that is where the issue lies.

Comment: If you are new to React, take a look at debugging, but since this is a small problem, you could simply do a console.log(index) in removePokemon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass an argument `index` to your function `removePokemon`:

You need to edit one row:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.props.removePokemon(i)}>Remove from team</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not passed `index` as argument to `onClick={this.props.removePokemon}`.

`index` inside `removePokemon` method refers the event object. So the code

`team.splice(index, 1)` evaluates to `team.splice(eventObject, 1)`.

That's why `splice` is removing first  element of the array.

You can change to `onClick={() => this.props.removePokemon(i)}`to remove the element you want.

Comment: `index` won't be `undefined` but an [event object](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)